# Proof of Implicit Function Theorem: special case

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, manifolds, proof-explanation, implicit-function-theorem

I was reading this [pdf](https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/5196) online on the Implicit Function Theorem (pg 18-19). I did not understand the last line : **Why** "*continuity of $f$ and uniqueness of $y$ implies continuity of $g$*"?

[image]

Comment: The uniqueness of $y$ imply that $g$ is a well defined function, can you do continuity now?

Comment: @Spotty I have an ugly argument for continuity: Suppose $f(x_a,y_a) = 0$, $y_1 < y_a < y_2$. Choose $y_1 <y_a' < y_a < y_a'' <y_2 $. By continuity of $f$ exist $|y_a'' -y_a'|/4>\delta > 0$  such that, $|x_b - x_a| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x_a,y_a') - f(x_b, z) | < \epsilon $ for $z = y_a' , y_a''$, where $\epsilon$ is chosen such that $f(x_b,y_a') < 0$ and $f(x_b,y_a'') > 0$. So we deduce  $y_a' < g(x_b) < y_a'' $. This implies continuity of $g$. \\\\ I was wondering if this proof was neat enough, or is there a shorter, more direct proof.

Comment: you can also show differentiability by using: $0=f(x+h,g(x+h))-f(x,g(x))$ for small enough $h$ and then using Lagrange Theorem for $f$ to get a nice inequality.

Comment: @Spotty May you elaborate on that argument?

Answer (score 1):

You have: $0=f(x+h,g(x+h))-f(x,g(x))$ by the multivariable Lagrange theorem for all small $h$ we have $\theta\in (0,1)$ such that:

$$f(x+h,g(x+h))-f(x,g(x))=f_x(x + \theta h, g(x) + θ(g(x + h) − g(x)))h+ 
f_y(x + \theta h, g(x) +\theta (g(x + h) − g(x)))(g(x + h) − g(x))$$
then by re-arranging we have:
$$|g(x+h)-g(x)|=\frac{|f_x(x + \theta h, g(x) + θ(g(x + h) − g(x)))|}{|f_y(x + \theta h, g(x) +\theta (g(x + h) − g(x)))|} |h|$$

this gives you continuity since the RHS is bounded by $M|h|$. Now that you know $g$ is continuous. Use the above equation with absolute value to get that the derivative at $x$ is $\frac{-f_x(x,g(x))}{f_y(x,g(x))}$.

If you need more details I guess I can add them.

Comment: what is the precise statement of your multivariable Langrange theorem?

Comment: look at the wikipedia page they do the same formulation at the end